# ListView "scrolls" if individual elements change their height

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

We have a `ListView` that displays a list of messages. When the page with the listview is navigated to, we scroll to a certain element with `ScrollIntoView`.

If the elements' height is fixed, this works like a charm. However if some of the elements contain images and the image is not cached, it is lazy loaded (as it should), and the item we scrolled to is moved out of the visible area because its predecessors have increased their height.

How can we force the ListView to preserve the bottommost visible item if a rearrangement due to height changes occurs?

Comment: Are any events fired when this occurs?

Comment: Sure, e.g. the expanding item's SizeChanged event is thrown twice. The first time when it is loaded (from 0,0 to x,y), the second time when the image was loaded (from x,y to X,Y).

Comment: The args for SizeChanged has the old size and new size.  Could you take the difference and then programatically offset the scrollviewer?

Comment: This would surely work for most lists, but if the list is virtualized and backed by a virtualized collection, the height is non-linear and thus you cannot just subtract the difference